# Better way than pass the same argument among classes in Python

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I have a question related to OOP but it should be implemented in Python.

I have a file user_inputs.py with all the user parameters.

In my main file, I have a function that is called first. This function is responsible to read all the user parameters and return a dictionary that will be used in the rest of the program.

My question is: what is the cleanest way to pass the user_parameters dictionary to all classes? I did it in 2 ways:

Method 1)

```
def read_user_parameters():
        # code to open and read all parameters etc.
        return user_parameters  # returns a dictionary with all the user parameters


Class A():
    def __init__(self, user_parameters):
        self.user_parameters = user_parameters


Class B():
    def __init__(self, user_parameters):
        self.user_parameters = user_parameters


user_parameters = read_user_parameters()
object_A = A(user_parameters)
object_B = B(user_parameters)
```

I don't like this way because I have dozens of classes that need to pass this argument. So I thought to create a parent class with the user parameters:

Method 2)

```
Class User_parameters():
    def  __init__(self, user_parameters):

    def read_user_parameters():
        # code to open and read all parameters etc.
        return user_parameters


Class A(User_parameters):
    __init__(self, user_parameters):
        super().__init__()
        # self.user_parameters comes from the parent class now


Class B(User_parameters):
    __init__(self, user_parameters):
        super().__init__()
        # self.user_parameters comes from the parent class now


object_A = A()
object_B = B()
```

I prefer method 2, however, when super() is initialized from Class A and Class B the function read_user_parameters() that reads the file will be called twice (multiply this by dozens of times). Is there a better solution than method 1 in which I call read_user_parameters() only once but doesn't need to pass the argument for all classes?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is it possible for you to have two objects with different user parameters?  You might make a base class with a user parameters attribute that only gets read once, and then every instance accesses it through inheritance.

Comment: You can make a singleton class instance and just reference that when creating the children. (though you wouldn't really need a parent in that case).

Comment: @PatrickHaugh The user parameters are always the same for all classes during the execution of the program. If the user changes the parameters the program will be executed again with the new parameters. The base class is not similar to the Class User_parameters(): in method 2?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Thanks, I will take a look at singleton classes.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have a single `UserParameters` class and two objects of the same class (Also class nameds are supposed to be camel-cases, not snake-cased)

```
#Single class for user parameters
class UserParameters:
    def  __init__(self, user_parameters):
        self.user_parameters = user_parameters

    def read_user_parameters(self):
        # code to open and read all parameters etc.
        return self.user_parameters

#Two objects
object_A = UserParameters("<params>")
object_B = UserParameters("<params>")
```

Comment: This is the same as using method 1 since you are passing the object as an argument to each class. I need to pass this object to more than 30 classes. I was looking for a more DRY method.
Object A and B implement other codes that will use user_parameters. Take user_parameter as a "global variable (a dict in this case)" that should be passed to more than 30 classes from several modules.

Comment: Your first method had a function and teo classes using that method. This is diffeent from that. Also let me edit the answer to come up with a more generic solution :) @Raphael

Comment: In fact, it's different, thanks. But the way you are using it is different from my question :-) Maybe I didn't explain it very well. The key idea is: how to read from a file only once, save the contents in a dictionary (user_parameters) and pass this dictionary to more than 30 classes without passing as an argument to each class? If I use a parent class the file will be read each time I call super().__init... so it's not good but close to what I'm looking for.